# CORS JAVA (ERRO)

Tags: java, api, cors

Estou tentando me conectar a uma API que foi feita em Java, porem sempre da erro ao tentar se conectar (quero alimentar um aplicativo mobile, feito em JS/Cordova).

Ao me conectar (via Browser) eu consigo, a API retorna e tudo funciona normal, mas quando eu instalo o app no celular, da erro 401. Falei com varias pessoas, e parece ser erro do CORS. O Problema é que a API não foi eu que desenvolvi, então pedi o codigo que libera o CORS antes de vir aqui. e ele me passou isso aqui.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern> /* </url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Alguem sabe me dizer se esta certo? ou qual a melhor forma para se fazer isso?

Comment: Então Rafael, a um tempo atrás tive um problema semelhante com um API, basicamente o CORS é um autorização que define quem esta autorizado a consumir dados da API, de uma olhada nesse [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296145/set-cors-header-in-tomcat/18850438#18850438], como estão definidos os headers da sua solicitação ?

Comment: Pelo teu comentário na resposta do LuKs Sys tu não tens acesso ao servidor. O código que ele te passou é uma configuração do servidor Tomcat. Tu precisas alterar o teu app para incluir os headers do CORS nas chamadas para a api.

Comment: Outra coisa que chama a atenção é que problemas com CORS só ocorrem quando tens uma página carregada a partir de um host querendo fazer chamadas Ajax para outro host. Em mobile isso não deve acontecer porque tuas chamadas não executam em um browser :).

Comment: @Grasshopper não entendi muito bem, mas sim, quando eu executo no Browser a API retorna corretamente, quando faço o build e vou executar no app tenho esse problema, o app esta sendo feito usando Cordova + F7. é a primeira vez que tenho esse problema, todos os outros projetos (com outro back), funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: @RafaelAugusto [401](https://httpstatuses.com/401) não é erro de `CORS`

Comment: @RafaelAugusto coloca o código onde você realiza a chamada para a API

Comment: Felizmente acabei refazendo o Back-End em NodeJS, todas as informações que passaram por cima eu passei para o outro desenvolvedor e infelizmente ele não conseguiu resolver, mas agradeço a todos que tentaram me ajudar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um filtro para liberar o CORS seria algo como:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
    chain.doFilter(req, response);
}
```

Como ele está usando o Apache CorsFilter, acho que falta coisa.

Seria algo como:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
       <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
        <param-value>10</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Fonte: [Using CORS Headers with JAVA](https://amodernstory.com/2014/12/27/using-cors-headers-with-java-example/)

Comment: Vou apagar meu comentário depois, mas adicione isto a sua resposta por favor: 1 - CorsFilter é um recurso provido pelo tomcat a partir da versão 7 (neste caso, para deixar a app portável, seria melhor ele optar pela primeira abordagem).

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi provavelmente você está criando um aplicativo feito com Ionic e debugando o app pelo chrome. Se este for seu cenário existe uma alternativa que resolve facilmente seu problema apenas instalando um plugin. CORS plugin : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Basta instalar e ativar o plugin e você não vai mais ter problemas. Espero ter ajudado

Comment: A questão não é debugar, debuggar eu consigo, a questão é quando eu rodo no celular, ai eu tenho problema com CORS. Quando eu testo o app pelo navegador, ele roda de boa, tras o retorno da API certinho. mas quando eu rodo pelo celular vou debuggar usando o Chrome,  ele da erro de CORS.

Comment: O servidor e seu celular estão na mesma rede?

Comment: Servidor? eu faço o build, gero a APK, o servidor onde a API está, está hospedado, eu só consumo ela. Como eu disse, no Chorme funciona (Não testei em outros navegadores), mas no celular, já da erro de cara, ai como faço de debugger pelo proprio Chorme (Android) ou Safari (IOS). Consigo ver os erros de Rede. E em ambas plataformas, gera o mesmo erro.