# Chamar lado servidor php com Ionic e AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

Olá, pessoal. Eu tenho essa dúvida do título que ainda não consegui sanar. Eu já procurei várias formas e até mesmo a forma convencional do angular:

> $http.post() ou $http.get()

Mas me retorno esse erro:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Agradeço qualquer ajuda!

Comment: Veja: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210731/cors-java-erro/211458#211458

Answer (score 1):

Este é um problema de CORS.

https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Ele acontece quando uma requisição é feita para sua API PHP a partir de um domínio diferente dela, no caso, do seu aplicativo utilizando o Ionic.

Para resolver isso, sua API PHP precisa ter os cabeçalhos do CORS configurados. Essa configuração vai depender da framework PHP que você está utilizando para criar as APIs.

Abaixo segue uma artigo de como fazer utilizando o Laravel.

http://en.vedovelli.com.br/2015/web-development/Laravel-5-1-enable-CORS/